# How distinguish inner context?

Tags: flutter

I wrote the code like `data: (data){Navigator.of(context).pop();},//here` to pop `showDialog` but actually other `Navigator.of(context)` was popped and figured out that I should distinguish inner `context` in `builder: (context) { //here2` from outer `context` but could not reach how to do that. Would somebody please give me some advise to solve this ?

```
    final authC = ref.watch(authFutureProvider);
    authC.when(
      data: (data){Navigator.of(context).pop();},//here
      error: (error, stackTrace) {},
        loading: () {
        final loading = 
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            showDialog(
            barrierDismissible: false,
            context: context,
            builder: (context) { //here2
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
        );
        });
      },
    );
```

Comment: You should not be calling the Navigator in a build() function.  It's ok to call it in a callback, or a post-frame, but never in the build().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can easily define different BuildContexts by giving them different names, like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext parentContext) {
    final authC = ref.watch(authFutureProvider);
    authC.when(
      data: (data){Navigator.of(parentContext).pop();},//here
      error: (error, stackTrace) {},
      loading: () {
        final loading =
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          showDialog(
              barrierDismissible: false,
              context: parentContext,
              builder: (context) { //here2
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
          );
        });
      },
    );
    return Widget();
}
```

However, that won't change the fact that the context I've named "parentContext" is the parent context! This is the context sent TO the Dialog, not the context of the Dialog itself.

If you want to pop whichever context is on top at the moment, you can define a GlobalKey variable like this:

```
//global.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GlobalVariable {
  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navState = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
}
```

Then, you can pop the current context like this, from anywhere:

```
import 'global.dart';

void func(){
  Navigator.pop(GlobalVariable.navState.currentContext!);
}
```

That should pop the Dialog IF the Dialog is currently on top...

But of course, if some other BuildContext is on top, then that will be popped, instead.  So make sure you write the proper conditions for that.

---

Edit:

You could also use `popUntil()`. If this happens to be the first screen, you can just write:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext parentContext) {
    final authC = ref.watch(authFutureProvider);
    authC.when(
      data: (data){Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route.isFirst);},//here
      error: (error, stackTrace) {},
      loading: () {
        final loading =
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          showDialog(
              barrierDismissible: false,
              context: parentContext,
              builder: (context) { //here2
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
          );
        });
      },
    );

    return Widget();
}
```

If not, then it's a bit more complicated to make it pop back to this particular screen... But you could use routeSettings, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As for the latter part, maybe i could understood that it's a way to pop the top Build context from anywhere with using GlobalKey variable right ?
By the way, even if the former explanation never solve this problem, but I wonder that if name the context like parentContext as you told,  I guess it was treated as undefined variables in this case right ?

Comment: If you look at my Edit, you'll see how I used the `parentContext`. In short, you have to name it where you define it. In my case, in the `Widget build(BuildContext parentContext) {}`. It is sometimes useful, but... I don't think it is what you want, right now. The rest of my Edit is probably more useful to you...

Comment: And yes, my code with the GlobalKey will pop whatever BuildContext is currently on top. That can be extremely useful in some situations!... (Probably more for pushing than for popping.) But again, I'm not sure this is the case for it. 

Comment: What is the problem, anyway? You want to show a spinner while waiting for data, and then when the data comes, you want the spinner to pop, but instead the spinner stays and the background pops? Is that it?

Comment: Yes, my problem was that spinner should be popped but  actually certain background was popped. To solve this problem, using GlobalKey to pop on top things like spinner in this case must be good way.

Comment: It works, so long as the user hasn't already dismissed the spinner, or pushed something else on top... But what I normally use in such cases is a `package:modal_progress_hud_nsn` with a StatefulWidget. You just define a bool, `showSpinner`, and whenever you want the spinner to show, you setState() and make `showSpinner` true. When you want to dismiss it, you setState() again and make `showSpinner` false. While it's true, the window is inactive, so the user can only leave the screen, but not change it.

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing you, but I just tried your former part to know what will happen in your original answer and figured out could not define parentContext in this kind of ansyc situation. and I used  `late` to define as variables but finally LateInitializationError occurred and could not define this.
As you know, this was not related to my original  question, but i felt there must be some case which I should several contexts in ansync situation, and just wanted to know how to define it just in advance.

Comment: Post a complete bit of code that I can run then, and which reproduces the error you're talking about. Then, I could solve it. Plz post it in an Edit in your answer.

Comment: Btw, the keyword "late" has nothing to do with async... "late" only means that you're declaring a non-nullable variable without giving it a value immediately (i.e. letting it be null for a while) but you promise to give it a value before its first use case.

Comment: Hi, sorry for sending back comment. And actually it worked as you had shown above   for using different `contents` name. Sorry for confusing you !

Comment: No problem!  (Feel free to upvote, if you found my answer useful!  Not a requirement, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

I strongly not recommend WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback to show loading because it takes time to render, so your app will load a loading function. It will make End-user can do multiple clicks on the button because the loading has not rendered yet.

this package is verylight and easy to use, the dismiss and show even different from regular widget, so you will not accidentally close your screen because wrong logic or back-end handler failure.

```
class LoadingExample {

showLoadingExample(){
EasyLoading.instance
  ..displayDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 2000)
  ..indicatorType = EasyLoadingIndicatorType.fadingCircle
  ..loadingStyle = EasyLoadingStyle.dark
  ..indicatorSize = 45.0
  ..radius = 10.0
  ..progressColor = Colors.yellow
  ..backgroundColor = Colors.green
  ..indicatorColor = Colors.yellow
  ..textColor = Colors.yellow
  ..maskColor = Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5)
  ..userInteractions = true
  ..dismissOnTap = false
  ..customAnimation = CustomAnimation();
}

dismissExampleLoading(){
EasyLoading.dismiss();
}
}
```

to call it simply do: *I recommend OOP so you can modify it in 1 place when you need.

```
LoadingExample().showLoadingExample();
or 
LoadingExample().dismissExampleLoading();
```

even you accidentally call show or dissmiss multiple time, the loading will not stack, and it will just recall or reset the animation. So your app will not crash

[Flutter_easyloading](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_easyloading)

Comment: thanks for your helpful comment and i will immediately check out the usage of the package and try it. After that I will note the result here !

Comment: Wow, this is really great package and finally I could adopt easily !!!  I could not find how to barrier background (not allowed user to tap anything during loading) , but only masktype property and do you know how to set this ?

Comment: Please forget above, as I could set it by ..userInteractions = false at config !

Comment: ..userInteractions = false, if you want to darken the half transparent backgroud you can use    ..loadingStyle = EasyLoadingStyle.custom and ..backgroundColor = Colors.white.withOpacity(0) and   ..maskColor = Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.1) and ..maskType = EasyLoadingMaskType.custom
      ..boxShadow = <BoxShadow>[]. you can combine it as you want, to check it further press Ctrl and left click on the parameter of easyloading

Comment: Sure, if you enjoy using the package for the best practice way to display loading without advanced bloc state management. You can checklist my answer and upvote it :). sorry that if my answer is different as you want but this answer is actually what you need.

Comment: No, actually it was my point and was helpful for me !